# Inserting new boolean method into class

Tags: java, logging, methods, linked-list, boolean

This question is very short and doesn't need any type of code to describe my problem. Basically, I don't know what my teacher is asking for. Here are her instructions:

"Add a method that takes a single parameter element which must be inserted into the log in such a way that the latter always appears to be sorted with respect to outcome of method compareToIgnoreCase() of class String."

If providing my code at the moment would help, here it is:

```
public class LinkedStringLog
{
    protected LLStringNode log;
    protected String name;

    public LinkedStringLog(String name)
    {
        log = null;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void insert(String element)
    {      
        LLStringNode newNode = new LLStringNode(element);
        newNode.setLink(log);
        log = newNode;
    }

    public boolean isFull()
    {              
        return false;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        int count = 0;
        LLStringNode node;
        node = log;

        while (node != null)
        {
            count++;
            node = node.getLink();
        }
            return count;
    }

    public boolean contains(String element)
    {                 
        LLStringNode node;
        node = log;

        while (node != null) 
        {
            if (element.equalsIgnoreCase(node.getInfo()))
                return true;
            else
                node = node.getLink();
        }
            return false;
    }

    public void clear()
    { 
        log = null;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String logString = "Log: " + name + "\n\n";
        LLStringNode node;
        node = log;
        int count = 0;

        while (node != null)
        {
            count++;
            logString = logString + count + ". " + node.getInfo() + "\n";
            node = node.getLink();
        }
            return logString;
    }

    public boolean insertSorted(String element)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The `return false` at the end was just something I put so it wouldn't show an error. Can anybody tell me what needs to be done or what she is asking for?

Comment: mm im not quite sure, but i think she wants that you insert in order

Comment: Yes, she is asking you to implement a method that adds to the `log` but keeps it sorted. The `log` must be sorted according to `compareToIgnoreCase()` before and after the insert operation. Maybe take a look at the javadoc for [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) for a specification of what you should be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess what your teacher wants you to achieve with your list and the new insert method, and that is that you have to find out in which place the new element is to be inserted relative to the already available content in the list. For that you are required to use the method [compareToIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) from the `String` class. This method comapre a string with another one ignoring the case and return an integer value which may be negative if the `other` string is grater than `this` string, a zero if both are equal and a positive integer if the other string is less than this string.

In short, your log has to be sorted no matter in which order you insert the strings into it.

Example:

Log contains:

```
Bar baz
```

You insert `bAt`

The log has to be then

```
Bar bAt baz
```